# What is the longform way of writing this pointer function code?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef

I'm new to C++. Still trying to wrap my brain around how callbacks work in this language.

I kind of understand pointer functions, but I don't get how this works.

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}

int subtract(int x, int y){
    return x-y;
}

typedef int(*t_yetAnotherFunc)(int,int);
t_yetAnotherFunc doMoreMath(char op){
    if(op == '+')
        return add; // equivalent of add(x,y), where x and y are passed from the function calling doMoreMath()?
    else if(op == '-')
        return subtract;
}

int main(){
    int x = 2;
    int y = 22;
    t_yetAnotherFunc yetAnotherFunc=    doMoreMath('+');
    int yetAnotherFuncOutput=           yetAnotherFunc(x,y);
    std::cout << yetAnotherFuncOutput << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

How do `x` and `y` go from `yetAnotherFuncOutput` to `yetAnotherFunc`?

Or another way of asking: What would this look like without `typedef`?

Comment: They're called " function pointers", not pointer functions. And TBH they're indeed a major pain. They exist in C++ because they map directly to a CPU instruction, but experienced C++ programmers usually prefer virtual functions or `std::function`.

Comment: Pre C++11 function pointers are notoriously terse and hard to read. You're better off using modern library utilities as, _e.g._, `using myfunc_ptr_t = std::add_pointer_t<int(int, int)>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from `typedef int(*t_yetAnotherFunc)(int,int)`

`t_yetAnotherFunc` is type that can point to a method which takes two `int`s as aruguments and returns an `int`.

`t_yetAnotherFunc doMoreMath(char op)` method returns either `add` or `subtract` based on `char op`. Here `add` and `subtract` at the return statements have to considered as addresses of those methods not a function call.

```
t_yetAnotherFunc yetAnotherFuncc = doMoreMath('+');
```

As per the definition of `t_yetAnotherFunc` now `yetAnotherFuncc` can be made to point `add` method.

If you need to call a function (here `add`) having arguments `(int x, int y)` using its pointer (here `yetAnotherFuncc`) then you need to supply its arguments via its pointer as `yetAnotherFuncc(x, y)`. This is accomplished by the below line.

```
int yetAnotherFuncOutput = yetAnotherFunc(x,y);
```

It makes a call to the function `add` with arguments `x`(2) and `y` (22) and the return value of `add` is stored in `yetAnotherFuncOutput`.

Without `typedef` it will be a complex definition as follows

```
int(*doMoreMath(char op))(int, int) {
  if(op == '+')
     return add
  else if(op == '-')
     return subtract;
}

int(*yetAnotherFunc)(int, int) = doMoreMath('+');
```

Answer (score 3):

A pointer to a function can be used just like any other function, and when you call it you get a result like calling any other function. It's like an *alias* of another function.

In your case you make an *alias* of the `add` function, and when you call `yetAnotherFunc` you are in fact calling `add`.

The statement

```
int yetAnotherFuncOutput=           yetAnotherFunc(x,y);
```

is equivalent to

```
int yetAnotherFuncOutput=           add(x,y);
```